# Undefined variable:title

Tags: laravel

I added migrate in database, but why getting error I don't know,  I am pretty new to Laravel, I don't know how can I fix this.

**Error is:**

> Undefined variable: title

**My code:**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Models\Abouts;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AboutusController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
      return view('admin.aboutus');
    }

    public function store(Request $request){
      $aboutus = new Abouts();

      $aboutus->$title = $request->input('title');
      $aboutus->$subtitle = $request->input('subtitle');
      $aboutus->$description = $request->input('description');

      $aboutus->save();
      return redirect('/abouts')->with('success','nice');
    }
}
```

Comment: `$aboutus->$title = $request->input('title');` should be 
`$aboutus->title = $request->input('title');`

Same like others

Comment: @PunitGajjar  FINALLY, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you can write this way also.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Models\Abouts;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AboutusController extends Controller
{
public function index(){
  return view('admin.aboutus');
}

 public function store(Request $request){
   $input = $request->all();
   Abouts::create($input); //here About us your model
   return redirect('/abouts')->with('success','nice');
 }
}
```

Comment: For the above code, We need to make sure that the request input name is matching with the column name of the table, Else it might throws an error!